# JTextArea not displaying what I tell it to

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

For some reason, I cannot get the JTextArea "answersTA" to display anything. Calls to append() and setText() do not update the information in the box.

Here's the goal of my program: Take in a string and store it to "word", take in a string and parse an int from it and store it to "num", feed those into the solutions() method, and display the array returned by solutions(). I cannot for the life me get anything to display.

```
public class CWGui extends JFrame
{
    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 400;

    private JLabel pattern, number, answers;
    private JTextField patternTF, numberTF;
    private JButton execute, exitB;
    private JTextArea answersTA;

    //Button handlers:
    private ExecuteButtonHandler eHandler;
    private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;

    public CWGui()
    {
        pattern = new JLabel("Enter the pattern: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        number = new JLabel("Enter the number of solutions: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        answers = new JLabel("Solutions: ", SwingConstants.LEFT);

        patternTF = new JTextField(10);
        numberTF = new JTextField(10);
        answersTA = new JTextArea();

        //SPecify handlers for each button and add (register) ActionListeners to each button.
        execute = new JButton("Execute");
        eHandler = new ExecuteButtonHandler();
        execute.addActionListener(ebHandler);
        exitB = new JButton("Exit");
        ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
        exitB.addActionListener(ebHandler);

        setTitle("Crossword Solution Generator");
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));

        //Add things to the pane in the order you want them to appear (left to right, top to bottom)
        pane.add(pattern);
        pane.add(patternTF);
        pane.add(number);
        pane.add(numberTF);

        pane.add(execute);
        pane.add(exitB);

        pane.add(answers);
        pane.add(answersTA);


        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private class ExecuteButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            try{
                String word = patternTF.getText(); 
                int num = Integer.parseInt(numberTF.getText());
                FileParser fp = new FileParser("TWL06.txt");
                List<String> dict = fp.getAllWords();

                CWSolution c = new CWSolution(dict);
                List<String> result = c.solutions(word,num);
                        answersTA.setText(result.toString());

            }
            catch(Exception t){}
        }
    }

    public class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CWGui generator = new CWGui();
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks more like your `CWSolution` is returning some kind of nothing from `solutions(word, num)`. Consider posting that code. Also never silently catch all exceptions. Because you are doing that anything could be the problem. Find out if an exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you make any update to the gui called from by the Event Dispatch Thread. This thread will update the gui so it wont freeze it, also because of this, make sure any process that might take awhile is run on the SwingWorker thread, which is separate from the EDT. The SwingWorker thread makes it possible to run in the background, while also giving you updates during the process. You can get a good description of these on the official docs. I just recently learned it and it helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that is not returning an exception?.

```
catch(Exception t){}
```

That line is **DANGEROUS**.

Change this

```
catch(Exception t){}
```

to something like this (catching general exception is not a good idea)

```
catch(Exception t){
 t.printStackTrace();// this only for debug purpose 
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,t.getMessage());
}
```

If it's not add classes to compile your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

```
List<String> result = c.solutions(word,num);
String[] array = new String [result.size()];
result.toArray(array);
answersTA.setText(array.toString());
```

Actually this is not necessary just put.

```
List<String> result = c.solutions(word,num);
answersTA.setText(result.toString());
```

What returns `c.solutions(word,num)` did you try to debug it?

Comment: Okay, I edited that line. Had no effect on the GUI output though :(

Comment: @user3078311 consider adding classes to let us test your code! cause in that way it's impossible, did you try debuging it?

Comment: There are 5 classes that run behind the CWSolution and FileParser. Is there a way to attach files? I don't want to paste in 5 classes worth of code haha

Comment: when I try to debug that line it never reaches that breakpoint, the GUI applet just runs

Comment: @user3078311 see my edit, for sure your code returns an exception, you have to catch it and do something with it.

Comment: If the debugger never reaches the breakpoint then an exception is almost certainly being thrown. Never silently catch all exceptions.

Comment: Good points, I only silent caught the exception because the FileParser has a throws clause and I know that if given the parameters I'm feeding it, it should't throw anything.

@nachokk - no exceptions were thrown when I added your edit, no JOptionPane popped up.

Comment: Erggg I can't get the debugger to tell me what "word" and "num" are storing. That would rule out something weird happening with CWSolution

Comment: @iNfluence consider making a correct example demonstrating your issue then.. it's impossible to help then and you will get bad and poor answer like mine

Comment: AH! I found it!! 

    execute.addActionListener(ebHandler);

needs to be eHandler not ebHandler!

Comment: @iNfluence considering accepting or upvoting the answer if it helps you to find the answer